# Triggering point to TBT Info in HereMaps Voice Guidance

Tags: here-api

From here maps Voice Guidance ,Exactly When Google TSS will speak about Maneuver Take left into X road ,Now take Right, like that.
Consider Navigation Distance 10km ,when trip started there is Turn left in 500m meters ,so when Google TTS will speak?before 300m or 200m ?
I want to know the triggering point to speak for My task to complete.
--suppose speaking Text is long(eg:Now keep right and then turn slightly right onto JC Road) Speaking logic distance will also change?
--Apart from TBT(Turn By Turn Info) here maps also triggering in middle to speak like ( After 250 meters keep left towards Hosur Road ) how this is calculating

So many questions is single please excuse me

Answer (score 0):

Interface for notifying NavigationManager.AudioPlayer functions used by NavigationManager. Clients can take over playback of audio files and TTS text strings by implementing this interface and submitting to NavigationManager.AudioPlayer.setDelegate

The audio will be played during the entire route, playing the audio based on distance calculation logic can not be done.